# Add GPT-4V (Vision) capability to Chatbot-ui (open-source ChatGPT clone by TypeScript)

Tags: typescript, artificial-intelligence, openai-api, chatgpt-api, gpt-4

How can I add GPT-4 Vision API to Chatbot-ui, which is a powerful open-source clone of ChatGPT, developed by McKay Wrigley.

It let's you use OpenAI AI models through your own API key, which is amazing. I've been using it for my persoanl use, and now I need to use gpt4v as well.

Github repo:
https://github.com/mckaywrigley/chatbot-ui

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on a project that might help you. I just added vision support a few hours ago. The project is called convo-lang. It doesn't handle the UI layer but it is fully capable of replicating a full ChatGTP experience including vision support and function calling. You are responsible for rendering to UI.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@iyio/convo-lang

https://github.com/iyioio/common/tree/main/packages/convo-lang

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).